# Comparative form of adjective "starving"

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, intensifying-adverbs, gradability

There is a way to say *hungrier*, but my question is whether there is any way to use the same form with *starve*. I searched and found nothing.

I would like to know the comparative adjective of *starving*.

Comment: I've always considered starving to be a binary state (i.e.you are starving or you're not).

Comment: Surely _starving_ is a participle being used as an adjective, and they don't have a comparative form. You can't say "Which prince is charminger?" or "Which cavalier is laughinger?"

Comment: *More starving* is grammatically a perfectly good comparative, just like *more interesting*. We don't say *interestinger* or *starvinger*.

Comment: This question belongs on English Language Learners, not here, as is evident from your supposition that starving can have a comparative in English.

Comment: Adding the -er suffix to an already end-state condition (starving) makes me think of the word "pregnanter."

Comment: @PeterShor I actually don't think you can have more starving people without that meaning you have more people starving, and some simple pokes via Google ngrams seem to agree with this. This is one of those gradability things where you can’t use degree modifiers on adjectives already “maxed-out” in their sense. It’s like how Romance languages that have retained Latin’s [absolute superlatives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/absolute_superlative) like IT *crudelissimo* meaning super-cruel or PT/ES *paupérrimo* meaning super-poor never let you make those have “more” of that maxed-out quality.

Comment: @KateBunting Good point, participial adjective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Words of two or more syllables usually don't form comparatives with *-er*. There are exceptions, (such as words like *hungry*, that end in *-y*) but this holds as a general rule.

When I read the title of your question, I had no idea what you meant by *starvinger*. In context, most people would understand it, but it certainly isn't a standard form.

You would have to use *more starving*, though (as KillingTime said in a comment) I don't find *starving* to be a concept that can be compared.

Comment: **I had no idea what you meant.**  My reaction as well.  I guessed that "starvinger" was a combination of "starving" and "scavenger".  I did not guess that it was a comparative for "starving".

Comment: See also: Comment at OP by @KateBunting above.

Answer (score 3):

## On the Non-gradability of “Extreme” Adjectives

Adjectives whose inherent sense is already an intensified or extreme quality cannot normally be made into comparative and superlative degrees, nor may be they be modified by the same sorts of words you can use on regular adjectives. Sometimes these ***non-gradable adjectives*** are called *extreme adjectives, strong adjectives*, or even *limit adjectives*. (But be careful: *limiting adjectives* are something else altogether.)

Extreme adjectives aren’t gradable because they already mean some quality that’s as intense as possible. They’re maxed-out already; they’re super-something. For example *boiling* means very hot, *freezing* means very cold, *ecstatic* 
means very happy, *starving* means very hungry, *spotless* means very clean,
and *giant* means very big.

So while you can say that something is very cold or that one thing is colder than another thing, you cannot really say that something is very freezing or that one thing is more freezing than another thing is. Only little children might ever say that their house was “gianter” than their neighbor’s house: we just don’t say things like that because they do not sound right to us.

Because *starving people* are already very hungry people, you cannot have starving people one day and more starving people the next. If you try, that *more* will be understood to apply **not** to the adjective *starving* but to the noun *people* instead. So if one country has more starving people than another one has, the first country’s people are not “more starving” people; it just means that there are more people starving in the first country than in the second.

Extreme adjectives *can* still take certain adverbs. You could be completely furious not very furious, or utterly spotless not very spotless, or truly starving not very starving, or entirely impossible not very impossible. Native speakers hearing these might attempt rescue readings that forced some sense into them, but it is not normal, common, or easily understood.

For most and possibly all of these, here and there you **can** find scattered published examples of non-gradable adjectives with a *very* or a *more* in front of them. But these are quite uncommon, and many sound “off”.  For example, here’s a [Google Books search for *very starving*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very%20starving%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) showing that it does occur, albeit rather rarely. A [similar search for *more starving*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more%20starving%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) has almost nothing but false positives in it because native speakers seldom say that in the sense you intend; that is, to somehow mean “more very hungry”.

As a non-native speaker learning English, you should learn the difference between “regular” adjectives that you *can* grade and compare on the one and, and “extreme” adjectives that you really *shouldn’t* do those things with on the other.

Comment: We _do_ use shortened forms, say 'fuller' for 'more nearly full', but 'starvingness' is probably harder to quantify and 'more [nearly] starving' not idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would submit that *stuffed* or *sated* might be extreme forms of *full*. :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that one might have the merest bit too much Christmas pudding on occasion? Well, a merer bit too much than sometimes?

Comment: Hmm. Can I be more starving than you? That's a grammatical possibility, and maybe even a semantic one. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Certainly you can be starving more than I am, for starving I am not. :)

Comment: @Andrew Leach I suppose you could be more starving than I am, should you be in the unfortunate circumstance of being closer to death than me through lack of nutrition. However, should matters ever reach that sad state, I suggest that the semantics would be the least of our concerns.

Comment: @tchrist That's true in a mathematical or logical sense, but grammar often doesn't work like that. If it did, nobody would attempt to use concordant double negatives, since everyone would already assume that a double negative is simply a positive. It says something about the natural wiring of our brains that we need to be taught and trained to think rationally.

Answer (score 0):

True starvation is such a rarity in our society that we lose sight of the original meaning of *starving*, and simply use it to mean "intensely hungry". In that role of course it can have a comparative and superlative uses, but like most words ending with *-ed* or *-ing*, only as a compound, not by inflection.

In its true sense, *starving* means undergoing a privation that will lead to death if not reversed.

Comparing with *a walking child*, where it makes no sense to describe a child as *more walking*, but rather to *have walked further*, so one can *have starved nearly to death*, or *only starved for a day*.